Pin tabs are not saved in Firefox
I accidentally closed Firefox, after that my pin tabs have disappeared. I tried to pin them again, but every time I close browser, they disappears. I didn't change anything in settings. I need these tabs to be pinned, what I should do to keep them pinned all the time?
Thanks for answering in advice!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pinned-tabs-keep-favorite-websites-open and https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-previous-session#w_troubleshooting. For example, if Clear History on shutdown is enabled, tabs are not remembered.
